# The partition function of a particle in a magnetic field diverges. Why?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, statistical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, partition-function

Using the *symetric gauge* $\mathbf{A} = \tfrac{B}{2} (-y, x, 0)$, the stationary states wave functions of a quantum particle in a constant and homogeneous magnetic field are
$$\tag{1}
\psi_{n m}(r, \varphi) = a \sqrt{\frac{n!}{\pi (n + |m|)!}} \, u^{|m|} \, L_n^{|m|}(u^2) \, e^{- u^2/2} \, e^{i m \varphi},
$$
where $u = a r$, $a = \sqrt{m |\omega|/\hbar}$ and $\omega = -\, q B / 2 \tilde{m}$ (the *Larmor angular frequency*).  The functions $L_n^k$ are the *associated Laguerre polynomials*.  Here: $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots, \infty$ and $m = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \dots, \pm \infty$.

The wave functions (1) are normalized and orthogonal. AFAIK, they form a complete set of orthogonal functions in the Hilbert space, for the cartesian 2D plane.  Take note that the 2D space accessible to the particle is infinite in size, so there are no special boundaries conditions on the wave functions (1) (excluding the one at the origin and $\psi(r \rightarrow \infty) = 0$).

The *Landau energy levels* are the following (these energy levels are degenerate):
$$\tag{2}
E_{nm} = (2 n + 1 + |m|) \, \hbar |\omega| + m \hbar \omega.
$$
For a negative charge: $q = - e$, we have $\omega > 0$, so the Landau energy levels could be separated in two parts (it's the reverse for $q > 0$):
\begin{align}
E_{nm} &= \hbar \omega \, (2 n + 1) \qquad \text{if $m < 0$,} \tag{3} \\[2ex]
E_{nm} &= \hbar \omega \, (2 n + 2 m + 1) \qquad \text{if $m \ge 0$.} \tag{4}
\end{align}
The first part is causing an issue for calculating the *partition function*:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Z} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\beta E_{nm}} \\[2ex]
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{-1} e^{-\beta E_{nm}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta E_{nm}} \\[2ex]
&= e^{- \beta \hbar \omega} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{-1} \Bigl( e^{-\beta \hbar 2\omega} \Bigr)^n + e^{- \beta \hbar \omega} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \Bigl( e^{- \beta \hbar 2 \omega} \Bigr)^n \Bigl( e^{- \beta \hbar 2 \omega} \Bigr)^m. \tag{5}
\end{align}
The second part is converging (it's a simple geometric series), but the first part is diverging since $E_{nm}$ doesn't depend on $m < 0$.  Notice that $2 \omega = e B/\tilde{m} > 0$ is the classical *cyclotron* angular velocity of the particle in the magnetic field.

So what is going on here?  Why this divergence?  What is the physical interpretation of this?  And does that mean that there's no thermodynamical quantities in this case?  I'm tempting in trying to replace $m = - \infty$ by $m = - M$, and doing the limit $M \rightarrow \infty$ after the statistical calculations, but I'm not sure this is a good idea.

---

**EDIT:** Replacing $m = - \infty$ by $m = - M$ and doing the limit $M \rightarrow \infty$ appears to work, but I never saw this calculation before and yet it's very easy to do.  It's equivalent of trashing the second part of (5), which is very strange since it implies that (4) doesn't contribute to the thermodynamical properties of the system.

AFAIK, the thermodynamical properties of the free particles in a magnetic field are not presented in the standard textbooks, and I'm wondering why.  Unless I'm mistaken, this system may be important, a least as a pedagogical example of Quantum Statistical Mechanics.

Comment: There is no mention of volume in your calculation so I assume you are working in infinite volume? I would expect the partition function to diverge in this limit, as the free energy should be extensive. How this translates into this particular divergence (if that is what is happening), however, is not obvious to me

Comment: @BySymmetry, the calculations are done in the infinite Cartesian plane.  The *quantum* partition function is $$\mathrm{Z} = \mathrm{Tr} \Bigl( e^{-\beta \hat{H}} \Bigr) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{m= - \infty}^{\infty} \langle n, m|\, e^{- \beta \hat{H}} \,|n, m \rangle = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{m= - \infty}^{\infty} e^{- \beta E_{n m}}.$$There's no integration in this case.  I guess that the divergence may be related ***implicitely*** to the infinite size of the Cartesian plane.

Comment: Sure, but $H$ is still implicitly dependent on the volume (or I suppose area) of the system, so we can still ask how does $Z$ vary with volume. We should recover the classical result in an appropriate limit, which should be an exponential dependence. If you repeat your calculation for a disk of fixed radius and a hard wall, what happens?

Comment: @BySymmetry, doing the exact calculation for a disk of area $A$ would be very difficult, since it imposes boundaries to the wave functions.  Solving the Schrödinger equation in this case would be horrible, AFAIK.  So my case is for $A = \infty$.  Replacing $m = - \infty$ by $- M$ is probably a cheap trick to insert a finite $A$.

Comment: Using a finite $M$ and then the limit $M \rightarrow \infty$ gives a finite energy average: $$\langle E \rangle = \frac{\hbar \omega}{\tanh (\beta \hbar \omega)}.$$  Under the usual limits of low and high temperatures ($\beta \hbar \omega \gg 1$ and $\beta \hbar \omega \ll 1$), we get the expected results: $\langle E \rangle \approx \hbar \omega \equiv \tfrac{1}{2} \, \hbar \omega_c$ (the ground state energy) and $\langle E \rangle \approx kT$, respectively.

Comment: Partition function for a hydrogenic electron also diverges. This is telling us that there is no likelihood that the hydrogen atom will be in a bound state in infinite volume. Probably something similar is happening with your problem.

Comment: See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/616996/partition-function-of-a-hydrogen-atom

Comment: @hft, I don't think this is related (while the atom problem is also very interesting).  For the atom, the stationary states of negative energy aren't a complete set of functions, since there are positive energy eigenstates too. In my case, AFAIK, the stationary states (1) are a complete set of functions, and the Landau energy levels are all positive, up to infinity.  There are no negative energy states in this open (infinite area) system.  There's no missing wave functions.  The similar issue, though, is the infinite size of the system.  I now believe this is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Making everything dimensionless so that $\hbar=1$:
$$
H = \frac12(p-A)^2\\
A = \frac\omega2(-y,x)
$$
with $\omega$ the cyclotron frequency, the usual theory of Landau level gives the spectrum of the Hamiltonian for $n\in\mathbb N$:
$$
E_n = \omega(n+1/2)
$$
with degeneracy (up to a numerical prefactor):
$$
D_n \propto \omega \mathcal A
$$
with $\mathcal A$ the area of the domain. Therefore, the partition function is calculated just like for the harmonic oscillator:
$$
Z \propto \mathcal A\frac{\omega/2}{\sinh(\beta\omega/2)}
$$

In your case, $\mathcal A$ is infinite, so you expect to have an infinite prefactor. This is just like a free particle which you precisely recover in the $\omega\to0$ limit. In fact, since you know the partition function exactly in this limit, you can deduce the numerical prefactor (the $2\pi$ comes from the definition of the quantum flux defined in terms of $h=2\pi$ in my dimensionless units):
$$
Z = 2\pi\mathcal A\frac{\omega/2}{\sinh(\beta\omega/2)}
$$

If you don't know the formula for the degeneracy, you can rederive it in many ways by regularising the sum. Your approach is not physically transparent. One way of seeing why it works is to realise that $(3),(4)$ both give the Landau levels. However, from (3), you have an infinite "constant" degeneracy (morally the same countable amount given by varying $m$, which captures the extensive degeneracy), while from (4), you only have a linear degeneracy:
$$
E_n = \omega(n+1/2) \\
D_n = n+1
$$
The latter will therefore be completely swamped by the former one, which is why it appears that you are neglecting the second term in (5). The tricky part is precisely to anticipate that $M$, your surface degeneracy, is proportional to $\omega$. Without appealing to the classical limit, you can justify this by looking at the wave function. You wan identify a characteristic length for the wavefunction at large distance:
$$
r_* \propto \sqrt{m+2n}a 
$$
(competition between the polynomial and the exponential). Therefore, if you want to localise your wavefunctions on disk of area $\mathcal A$, it amounts to bounding:
$$
m+2n\leq \omega \mathcal A
$$
and then sending $\mathcal A$ to infinity. This regularises your sum and dividing by $\mathcal A$, you get a finite well defined limit.

For completeness, I'll also add other standard regularisation methods.

One approach is to take a large finite domain. If you want to keep using the symmetric gauge, you can take for example a disk with hard boundaries (indeed, there is no issue of flux quantisation in this case). As you've already commented, this is difficult to implement. You would need to investigate the zeros of hypergeometric functions. Plus you can anticipate that the spectrum would be complicated as the hard boundary would generate the discrete version of chiral edge states.

Another approach compatible with the rotation invariance of the symmetric gauge is to add a harmonic trap:
$$
H = \frac12(p-A)^2+\frac{\omega_0^2}2(x^2+y^2)
$$
This has the advantage of not altering your wavefunctions, and it is essentially the same situation up by a reparametrization. Explicitly, your previous spectrum was:
$$
E_{mn} = \omega\left(n+\frac{m+|m|}2+\frac12\right)
$$
it is now changed to:
$$
E_{mn} = \sqrt{\omega_0^2+\left(\frac\omega2\right)^2}\left(2n+|m|+1\right)-m\frac\omega2
$$
You can check that $\omega_0=0$ gives your spectrum, and that the effect of $\omega_0$ is to lift the degeneracy of (3). As a sanity check, you can also verify that you recover the 2D harmony oscillator when $\omega=0$.

Let:
$$
\Omega = \sqrt{\omega_0^2+\left(\frac\omega2\right)^2}
$$
It is not hard to compute the new partition function which is now finite, it's just geometric series:
$$
Z = \frac1{2\sinh(\beta\Omega)}\left(1+\frac1{e^{\beta(\Omega-\omega/2)}-1}+\frac1{e^{\beta(\Omega+\omega/2)}-1}\right)
$$
Sending $\omega_0\to0$, you get:
$$
Z = \frac1{2\sinh(\beta\Omega)}\frac1{\beta(\Omega-\omega/2)} = \frac{\omega/2}{\sinh(\beta\omega/2)}\frac1{\beta\omega_0^2}
$$
While formally, it may seem that just sending $\omega_0\to0$ should do the trick, you'll need to also add a temperature dependence. Indeed, you want to reproduce hard boundaries, whose position is temperature independent. By introducing "soft" boundaries, the effective size of the trap acquires a temperature dependence, which you need to compensate by scaling $\omega_0$ appropriately. Either by thinking classically by assuming that the effective domain is a disk whose radius is the root mean square distance, by dimensional analysis, or just to cancel the extra $\beta$ in the partition function, you obtain the scaling:
$$
\omega_0 \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta\mathcal A}}
$$
Now sending $\mathcal A\to\infty$ does send $\omega_0\to$, but not uniformly in temperature. You will thus obtain the correct final partition function.

You can already see how the trick works without magnetism $\omega=0$. In this case:
$$
Z = \frac1{(2\sinh(\beta\omega_0/2))^2} \to Z_0 \\
Z_0\propto \frac{\mathcal A}\beta
$$
since I know the exact partition function $Z_0$, I can even figure out the correct numerical prefactor:
$$
\omega_0 = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\beta} \mathcal A}
$$

You'll notice that in practice, this method is essentially the same as yours. Instead of using a hard cutoff for the first infinite sum of (5), I instead use an exponential cutoff which is physically more justifiable. In your case, the cutoff parameter $M$ acquires a magnetic dependence, whereas mine picks up a thermal dependence, both of which can be justified physically. The mathematical correspondence for the two is:
$$
M = \frac\omega{\beta\omega_0^2}
$$
so that you have both scalings:
$$
\begin{align}
M &\propto \omega\mathcal A & \omega_0 &\propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta\mathcal A}}
\end{align}
$$

In a similar spirit, a simpler way would be would be to add a harmonic trap not for the position but for the cyclotron orbit centers. They are the independent (unlike position which does not commute with the original Hamiltonian) degrees of freedom responsible for the large degeneracy in the first place. This gives:
$$
\begin{align}
v &= (v_x,v_y) & v_x &= p_x-A_x & v_y &= p_y-A_y \\
R &= (X,Y) & X &= x-\frac{v_y}\omega & Y &= y+\frac{v_x}\omega \\
\end{align}\\
H \to H+\frac{\omega_0^2}2(X^2+Y^2)
$$
This one also can be solvable with your wavefunctions, but has the advantage of being solvable using ladder operators for $v$ and $R$. You'll need the same scaling in temperature for $\omega_0$ to recover the correct limit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't like the idea of a "soft boundary", for which $\omega_0$ depends on the temperature and the area $A$, just to get rid of the extra "equipartition relic" of $k T$ in the energy average.  This feels very arbitrary and "patchy"!  The true physical way would be to solve the real quantum mechanical problem with a circular boundary imposed to the eigenfunctions (but this is the very difficult way, of course).

Comment: I guess it depends on your application. Soft boundaries are actually more realistic for experimental setups. Take for example cold atom experiments, you usually do not have solid boundaries but rather an optical trap which can accurately be modelled as a harmonic trap. The main advantage of this method is that it is physically transparent and analytically tractable.

Answer (score 1):

I may have solved my issue (thanks to @By Symmetry for the hint).  Indeed, the divergence appears to be related to the infinite area covered by the quantum system in 2D.  We could consider the similar system in the classical limit:
$$\tag{A}
\mathrm{Z}_c = \int e^{-\beta H(x, p)} \, \frac{d^2 p \, d^2 x}{(2 \pi \hbar)^2},
$$
where the classical hamiltonian is (using the symetric gauge $\mathbf{A} = \frac{B}{2}(-y, x, 0)$)
$$\tag{B}
H(x, p) = \frac{(\mathbf{p} - q \mathbf{A})^2}{2 m} = \frac{(p_x + m \omega y)^2}{2 m} + \frac{(p_y - m \omega x)^2}{2 m}.
$$
Integral (A) could be evaluated for an arbitrary *finite* area $A = \pi R^2$:
$$\tag{C}
\mathrm{Z}_c = (2 \pi m k T) \int_{A} \frac{dx \, dy}{(2 \pi \hbar)^2} = \frac{m A k T}{2 \pi \hbar^2}.
$$
This classical partition function would diverege if $A \rightarrow \infty$.  Now, using a finite $m = -M$ in my quantum sum (5), with $M \gg 1$, truncates the sum:
$$\tag{D}
\mathrm{Z} \approx \frac{M}{e^{x/2} - e^{- x/2}}, 
$$
where $x = \beta \hbar \omega_c$ (and $\omega_c = 2\omega = e B/m$).  For high temperatures (semi-classical regime: $x \ll 1$), the expression (D) reduces to
$$\tag{E}
\mathrm{Z} \approx \frac{M}{eB} \, \frac{m k T}{\hbar}.
$$
Comparing the classical (C) to the semi-classical (E) implies
$$\tag{F}
M = \frac{eB}{2 \pi \hbar} \, A = \frac{A}{L_B^2}.
$$
The constant $L_B = \sqrt{h / e B}$ is a kind of "magnetic lenght" between the quantum states.  So it becomes clear that $M \rightarrow \infty$ is related to the infinite area system.

Comment: Why don't you mention that it was the user @By Symmetry who pointed out the issue with the volume/area?!

Comment: @TobiasFünke, I added a comment about his hint.

Comment: Another way to regularise your sum is to add a harmonic trap, and let the parameter go to zero. If you want to add boundaries, in the quantum case, you'll need to watch out for flux quantisation, not all areas are possible. Btw, it is more common to use the cyclotron frequency $\omega=qB/m$ which represents the angular speed of the classical circular orbits, this gives you the usual Landau levels without the confusing extra factor $2$.

Comment: @LPZ, I agree about the frequency, but using $\omega_c$ everywhere would add an extra $\frac{1}{2}$ everywhere (energy, and in the wave functions).  About the boundary conditions, the flux quantization would come automatically if we impose the cancellation of the wave functions on the boundary.

Comment: @LPZ, I tried your suggestion of adding a quadratic potential (your "harmonic trap").  It works, but then there's apparently a subtlety.  After calculating the average energy with both methods and applying the proper limit, there's a difference of $k T$ in the average energy.  The harmonic trap appears to leave a $k T$ that stays even after its parameter goes to 0.

Comment: @LPZ, more precisely, from my method of using $M \gg 1$, I get the following average:$$\langle E \rangle = - \frac{\partial }{\partial \beta} \ln \mathrm{Z} = \frac{\hbar \omega}{\tanh (\beta \hbar \omega)},$$ while adding a 2D potential energy $U = \tfrac{1}{2} \, m \omega_0^2 r^2$ to the quantum Hamiltonian (with $\omega_0 \rightarrow 0$ after the calculations), I'm finding $$\langle E \rangle = k T + \frac{\hbar \omega}{\tanh (\beta \hbar \omega)}.$$

Comment: @LPZ, and doing the same at the classical partition function level (the calculations are much easier!), I get the same result. The harmonic trap $U = \tfrac{1}{2} \, m \omega_0^2 (x^2 + y^2)$ leaves an extra $k T$ term that doesn't disappear after $\omega_0 \rightarrow 0$.