# Partition Function of a Hydrogen Atom - How it is derived?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hydrogen, orbitals, partition-function

It is well-known that the Partition Function of Hydrogen Atom diverges if we calculate in naive manner. And I could find the partition function named Brillouin-Planck-Larkin partition function which gives proper physical effect (from SE):

- [Partition Function of a Hydrogen Atom](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/616996/partition-function-of-a-hydrogen-atom)
- [Partition function of a hydrogen gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4394/partition-function-of-a-hydrogen-gas)
  $$Z_{BPL}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 [\exp (-\beta E_n)-1+\beta E_n]\; , $$

where $E_n=R(1-1/n^2)$ (the ground state is at zero energy) and $R$ is the ionization energy.

But when I tried to follow how it was derived, too much of advanced concepts popped up. Currently I am stuck in the papers discussing them:

- https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1986apj...310..723r
- https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/andp.201200728

As I currently have no access to the scientific papers which is cited, and as my knowledge about statistical mechanics is limited to basic freshman graduate level, I could not follow the argument successfully. So, my questions are:

1. What assumption is made for deriving this partition function?
2. What physical approximation is made while deriving this equation?
3. How 1,2 is combined to derive that partition function?
4. Is $[\exp (-\beta E_n)-1+\beta E_n]/Z_{BPL}$ can be used as a probability of a bound hydrogen electron in (n,l,m) state?

Comment: Not directly related but here's another way to calculate the partition function:https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Energy-levels-of-atomic-hydrogen-in-a-closed-box%3A-A-Capitelli-Giordano/49ca22024d4f4072fa95ccca539f334982187220